# ¿Como enviar correctamente datos de un select de HTML a una base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mvc, arraylist

estoy trabajando en mvc y tengo unos datos que recopilo de la BD de la sigueinte manera:

```
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="nuevaCategoria" name="nuevaCategoria" required>

              <option value="">Selecionar proyecto</option>

              <?php

              $item = null;
              $valor = null;

              $categorias = ControladorCategorias::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

              foreach ($categorias as $key => $value) {

                echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["categoria"].'</option>';
              }

              ?>

</select>
```

De esta manera obtengo los datos que quiero en el select:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora lo que quiero es obtener el valor de ese *id* y el de *categoria* tal como se ve aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para meterlo en mi base da datos como se ve uso un solo id en el html de nombre *nuevaCategoria*, pero al llamarlo en mi controlador en vez de insertar los dos valores inserta solo el de el *id*:

```
$tabla = "productos";

            $datos = array("id_categoria" => $_POST["nuevaCategoria"],
                           "nomProyecto" => $_POST["nuevaCategoria"],
                           "descripcion" => $_POST["nuevaDescripcion"],
                           "tipoM" => $_POST["nuevaMedida"],
                           "stock" => $_POST["nuevoStock"],
                           "precio_compra" => $_POST["nuevoPrecioC"],
                           "precio_venta" => $_POST["nuevoPrecioV"]);
```

No se si lo estoy haciendo bien, ¿que tengo que hacer para que me envie el id en su columna correspondiente y el de categoria en su columna correspondiente?

Comment: Pues basicamente si vas a insertar solo el id de "categoria" en la tabla "productos" solo necesitas tu post de "nuevaCategoria", ahora bien dentro de "$datos" posees o estas leyendo nuevamente "nuevaCategoria" para "nomProyecto" y "descripcion" pues en este caso estas redundando datos solo debes usar el id de categoria..

Comment: Ya vi porque me enviaba numero en vez de letras, era error en el modelo, pero aun asi el error persiste en como envio los valores por separado

Comment: Cuando dices _categoría en su columna correspondiente_ te refieres a que _Bruso_ se guarde en _nomProyecto_?

Comment: Así es a eso me refiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, un campo tipo `select` envía por defecto el atributo `value`.

Con `jQuery` puedes capturar el `text` de tu `select` y asignarle ese texto a un `input` que puede estar oculto con el atributo `hidden`

Finalmente, envías por `POST` tanto `idCategoria` como `nuevaCategoria`

```js
//Cuando se hace la selección
$("select").change(function(){

  //Normalmente se envía el value del select
  var idCategoria = $("#idCategoria").val();
  console.log(idCategoria);
  
  //Puedes capturar el texto seleccionado
  var nuevaCategoria = $("select option:selected").text();
  
  //Y asignar el texto al input
  $("#nuevaCategoria").val(nuevaCategoria);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-lg" id="idCategoria" name="idCategoria" required>
  <option value="">Selecionar proyecto</option>
  <option value="2">Bruso</option>
</select>
<!-- Puedes crear un input y ocultarlo agregando el atributo hidden -->
<input id="nuevaCategoria" name="nuevaCategoria">
<!-- Envías el nombre de la categoría a la BD -->
```

```
$datos = array("id_categoria" => $_POST["idCategoria"],
      "nomProyecto" => $_POST["nuevaCategoria"],
      ... el resto del array...
```

Comment: Ok ahora lo checo

Comment: Hola lo he usado y funciona bien pero en el input me aparece ´´´10Bruso´´´

Aque se debera ?

Comment: 10 es el `id` de _Bruso_? De ser así, es posible que estés capturando con `jQuery` tanto el `val` como el `text` de tu `select`. Estas líneas son innecesarias y solo las puse en el ejemplo para mostrarte como funciona `var idCategoria = $("#idCategoria").val();` al igual que `console.log(idCategoria);` las puedes remover y probar si de esta manera solo te lleva el nombre de la categoría al `input`

Comment: Vale está bien de hecho probé otra función del jQuery pero manteniendo el código que me pusiste arriba y ya quedo, muchas gracias